# MPI: Processor does not go up to 100% on a single MPI process

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mpi, cpu-usage

I have a simple client-server program written in C using sockets. The server opens a new pthread for each request. On each new opened thread, I do a CPU intensive task (matrix multiplication).

I have a CPU with 2 physical cores and 4 logical processors.

When I run 4 clients, the server opens 4 threads, each thread is assigned on a logical processor and the CPU goes to 100% (usage).

If I run the clients one by one at a 5 seconds delay, I can see very clear how the CPU goes from 25% (one client), to 50% (two clients), to 75% (three clients) and finally to 100% (4 clients). It's a pretty normal behaviour.

However, if I embed the **entire server code** into a MPI process (only one MPI process), the CPU does not raise more than 50% no matter how many clients I start.

Why is this happening?

Thank you respectfully

Comment: Possibly the MPI launcher limits the CPU set of the executed binary. Check with `sched_getaffinity`, your MPI manual. For more help provide information about MPI implementation, version, how you launch the MPI binary and your OS...

Comment: If your MPI implementation is Open MPI, try passing `--bind-to none` to `mpiexec` / `mpirun`.

Comment: if you are unsure of how your tasks are pinned, you can simply `mpirun ... grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status`

Comment: Hristo Illiev: Your solution worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer to this question / problem is the following:

As Hristo Iliev said in a comment to my question, passing **--bind-to none** to the mpirun command solves the problem.

This option actually binds a MPI process to a specific object (see [the manual](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpirun.1.php) for more details).

By default, each MPI process is bound to a physical core. I have 2 cores on my machine, so the maximum usage of the CPU that I can get will be around 50%.

Setting the binding to none removes that constraint and now each MPI process will be bound to a logical core, which allows my CPU to get to 100%.